how pass a value from one Component to another Component in ReactJs?
I know how to pass data from parent component to child component but how can i pass data to an independent component ?
for example suppose to we have a component with this name : Test in Test component we have a value how we can pass this value to another component without i include it on first component ?
i write simplified of my code here
import {useState} from 'react';

const Test = () => {
    const [x,setX] = useState(0);


    const handleClick = () => {

        setX(x+1);
  
        };
    console.log(x);

    return(
    <div><div  onClick={handleClick} ref={ref}></div></div>
    )
}
export default Test;

on above code i have a value his name is x , i write bellow two other component

const Exit = () => {


    return(
<div>
    <p>Exit sec</p>
    <Score />
</div>)
}

export default Exit;

above component has a child component his name is Score and Exit component is header of site
const Score = () => {

   return(
    <div><p style={{color:"white"}}>YOUR SCORE IS {i want to put x value here} </p></div>
   )
}

export default Score;

please look at to above code i write in {} i want to put and show x value here . so how can i do this ?
finally i add these to index.js as bellow code
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <Exit/>

    <Routes> 
      <Route path='/' element={<Test />} />  

    </Routes>
  </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);




This article in react's documentation may be helpful to you: https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components . The short version is: you lift the state up to the common parent, and then pass it down as props to the children that need it.

There are multiple ways to move data between independent components. These include creating react context or using global state management libraries such as redux. When I look at your situation, it seems that creating context is sufficient. I leave the documentation below on how to create the context.
Documentation:https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext

IF You want to share a data between multiple independent component in react js
then you should below methods :

React Context
Redux
State Management Libraries: Redux , MobX , Recoil


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
